# Javascript RegEx global string search for underscore character(_)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am horrible with RegEx and I have been using this [online tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) for some time now and still can not find what I need.

So I have the string "2011_G-20_Cannes_summit". I want to replace all the underscores (_) with spaces.

So I want something like this:

```
var str = "2011_G-20_Cannes_summit";
str.replace(/_/g," "); or str.replace(/\_/g);
```

Though neither is working...

What am I missing?

Comment: All strings in JavaScript are immutable. That means that, among other things, all string functions return the result instead of modifying the actual string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works fine. The `replace` method doesn't modify the existing string, it creates a new one. This will do what you want:

```
var str = "2011_G-20_Cannes_summit";
str = str.replace(/_/g," ");
```

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to re-assign the variable. Also I had the regex in quotes! >.<